# It's possible to build a game using other project's ntf?

Tags: ethereum, ntfs, solana

As in the title, It's possible to build a game using other project's ntf? How can I do that?
For example, a game where in the 3D space, players can add frames of their own ntfs in his room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just have to get the person's NFTs given their wallet address.

To do this, make an API call to the Blockchain API on their ["Get Address's NFTs" endpoint](https://docs.theblockchainapi.com/#tag/Solana-Wallet/paths/%7E1v1%7E1solana%7E1wallet%7E1nfts/get). You just have to supply the wallet's public key.